# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. No such file or directory

Tags: hive

Getting the below exception in Hive on running simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`.

> Job Submission failed with exception
>   'org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIOException(No such file or
>   directory)' FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. No such file or
>   directory

No issues occurs on simple `SELECT * FROM Table`. 
 
Please suggest where might be the problem. Hive execution engine is MR. 
**Full stack trace of error** :

> 2017-07-18T07:18:52,744 ERROR [main]: exec.Task (:()) - Job Submission
>   failed with exception
>   'org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIOException(No such file or
>   directory)' ENOENT: No such file or directory     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:729)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:502)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:602)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:190)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:575)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:570)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:570)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:561)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:433)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1858)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1562)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1313)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>
> 2017-07-18T07:18:52,745 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (:()) - FAILED:
>   Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. No such file or
>   directory

Comment: what is your map task and reduce task memory allocated to your cluster?

Comment: Hive execute a MapReduce code when you try to do aggregation. Simple 'select * from table ' does not perform any MapReduce . so, It is quite clear that your cluster is that you're cluster have configuration problem while doing MapReduce. Can you please share your configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Try checking permissions on hadoop tmp dir. The path to this directory is configured for example in `core-site.xml`. The property name is `hadoop.tmp.dir`. 
I had a similar issue as the one you described and it was caused by the user, under which the MR job was being executed, not having write permission to that location.